# Sorting ACF Relationship field by the order specified by the author

Tags: wordpress, field, relationship, advanced-custom-fields

I'm looking to achieve the same functionality as described in this post: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/order-by-sorting-in-relationship-field/

As shown in the link above, I'm looking to display related posts in the frontend in the order they were added to the relationship field (or subsequently reordered via drag and drop).

I've added the code on `functions.php` file, but it doesn't seem to be working.
How can I sort the ACF Relationship field by the order specified by the author?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched this on Elementor too, and I found this way.

> https://developers.elementor.com/docs/hooks/custom-query-filter/

Please add this code on your theme `function.php` file.

```
/**
 * Order the posts in the query by post__in.
 * @since 1.0.0
 * @param \WP_Query $query The WordPress query instance.
 */
function my_query_by_different_order( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'post__in' );
}
add_action( 'elementor/query/YOUR_QUERY_NAME', 'my_query_by_different_order' );
```

And add YOUR_QUERY_NAME [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrQWw.png).